# How to add and check in code in Azure DevOps?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm not seeing source control explorer option in VS using Azure DevOps.

How to connect and check in the code?

Comment: This option is disabled when your project does not contain a TFVC-repo. new projects in AzureDevOps are using git as default repo type, check your project in DevOps

Comment: just use git like you normally would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default team projects contains a git repository. You have two options:

1. Use git and clone a repository to local hard ([Quickstart: Code with Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/code-with-git?view=azure-devops), [Share your code with Visual Studio 2017 and Azure Repos Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017?view=azure-devops))
2. Add TFVC repository and use Source Control Explorer:

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]